# How to add multiple mime with same suffix in wordpress?

Tags: uploads

I'm having problem adding archive files to wordpress.

The original `$allowed_mime_type` is using `application/zip`, while there are other mime type of `.zip` like `application/x-zip-compressed`, `application/zip-compressed` and `application/octet-stream`.

While an array can only allow one suffix, `array('zip' => 'application/octet-stream')`, I'm wondering how to add mime type without adding strange suffixes.